# Find class object on HashSet

Tags: java

```
Dogs a = new Dogs("Samy", 5, "Terrier");
Cats b = new Cats("Lucas", 1, "Siames");
Set<Protectora> animales = new HashSet<Protectora>();
animales.add(a);
animales.add(b);
```

How do I find only `Cats`?

Comment: instanceof operator can tell whether its a cat or a dog

Answer (score 3):

Use the `instanceof` keyword:

```
Set<Cat> cats = new HashSet<Cat>();
for (Object o : animales) {
   if (o instanceof Cat) cats.add(o);
}
```

Hopefully, your `Cat` and `Dog` classes extend some parent class, like `Animal`, in which case you would write:

```
Set<Animal> animals = new HashSet<Animal>();
animals.add(dog);
animals.add(cat);
//add more animals here
Set<Cat> cats = new HashSet<Cat>();
for (Animal a : animals) {
   if (a instanceof Cat) cats.add((Cat) o);
}
```

Comment: On class Cat...
public void eat(){...}

How use it HashSet cats?

Comment: `for (Cat c : cats) { c.eat(); }`

Comment: `if (o instanceof Cat) cats.add(o);` This requires a cast:  `if (o instanceof Cat) cats.add((Cat)o);`. `o`'s static type isn't `Cat`

Comment: @ThomasShields No worries, it's a compiler error ;-)